# understanding opencv stereoCalibrate function output

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have a dual camera set up and trying to make AR things on it. after stereo calibration and rectification, left and right image works great, epipolar line align well.

I detect the AR marker with one image and would like to render it on the other image with proper camera shift.

stereoCalibration gives the relation between two camera like:

```
R: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d
   data: [ 9.9922768917754268e-001, 2.4924911359451081e-002,
       3.0377194976358678e-002, -2.4063699016973375e-002,
       9.9930712233274999e-001, -2.8393901539922377e-002,
       -3.1063862775397383e-002, 2.7640984945580323e-002,
       9.9913513219219230e-001 ]
T: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 1
   dt: d
   data: [ -5.5054479009004126e+001, -7.1894766441986058e-001,
       -2.8661303301073544e+000 ]
```

how should I understand this? particularly the translation vector[-55.05,-0.718, -2.866]? is this in pixel unit?

in the rendering part, I use Ogre and makes a customized projection matrix(obtained from the camera calibration matrix). I make a translation matrix with vector[x,y,z], and multiple it to the customized projection matrix. In what unit would these correlated? snap of my code works like:

```
double pMatrix[16];
    camParams.OgreGetProjectionMatrix(camParams.CamSize,camParams.CamSize, pMatrix, 0.05,50, false);
    Ogre::Matrix4 PM(pMatrix[0], pMatrix[1], pMatrix[2] , pMatrix[3],
            pMatrix[4], pMatrix[5], pMatrix[6] , pMatrix[7],
            pMatrix[8], pMatrix[9], pMatrix[10], pMatrix[11],
            pMatrix[12], pMatrix[13], pMatrix[14], pMatrix[15]);    

.....

//translate the camera a little for the right display
    Ogre::Matrix4 matrix_translate;
    matrix_translate.makeTrans(Ogre::Vector3(-0.3,0.0,0.0));
    Ogre::Matrix3 matrix_rotate;

    camera_right->setCustomProjectionMatrix(true, matrix_translate*PM);
    camera_right->setCustomViewMatrix(true, Ogre::Matrix4::IDENTITY);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you calibrate your camera system, you had to input the size of the grid pattern, in terms of a unit, and the translation vector shares the same unit.

I'm not quite familar with Ogre, but i think there must be a global coordinate system in you ogre scene, and that coordinate system must have a specified unit.

Comment: thanks for the insight, I check my cameras, and the translation vector do share the same unit with my calibration grid pattern. In a AR rendering, usually, we use the AR marker as the world coordinate, and solvePnp() to find the rotation and translation vector to the camera coordinate. Though I am not quite sure Ogre use kind of camrea coordinate as global coordinate system, I use these ratio to shift the camera. looks fine. Thanks！